# How to await only last thread declared in a loop in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, oop, object

I have a `foreach` loop that goes through objects in a list, and calls a method:

```
foreach(var obj in objList)
    {
         Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => obj.Method());
    }
```

However, how do I make it so that I await only the last thread declared, so that all the threads run in parallel? If I do `Task task = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => obj.Method());`, the loop awaits every thread, which is not what I want.

Comment: Tasks are not threads. You probably want to use Task.WhenAll.

Comment: "the loop awaits every thread, which is not what I want." that's completely incorrect, the code shown only creates new tasks, without waiting for any single one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep track of the task that gets created, and await it after your loop is done.

Even though you say you want to await only the last thread, I'm taking artistic license to interpret your real need: you want to ensure all the Tasks are happening concurrently, and then you want to wait for them all to complete.

```
var tasks = objList.Select(obj => Task.Run(() => obj.Method())).ToList();
await task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Good point. I changed StartNew to Task.Run. Regarding ToList(), I hesitate to let thread-generating methods sit around in a deferred LINQ object. If someone tries doing something with `tasks` after they are awaited, all that work will get re-executed. I've found the safety of materializing those tasks to be worth the tiny extra bit of overhead that ToList() adds.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for only the last task would lead to problems:

- Tasks run concurrently, there are no guarantees that the last task finishes last
- You would not be able to catch / handle errors despite the last task

You should `await` all tasks at once:

```
var tasks = objList.Select(o => Task.Run(o => o.Method());
await Taks.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: I would delete everything before the "a better solution".